# Getting the 'thumbnail ID' from last product category term in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, categories, taxonomy-terms

I am trying to add new portfolio pragmatically When I add new category in WooCommerce.

My code is :

```
function programmatically_create_post() {

$author_id = 1;
$taxonomy     = 'product_cat';
$orderby      = 'id';
$show_count   = 0;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
$pad_counts   = 0;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
$hierarchical = 1;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
$title        = '';
$empty        = 0;

$args = array(
    'taxonomy'     => $taxonomy,
    'orderby'      => $orderby,
    'show_count'   => $show_count,
    'pad_counts'   => $pad_counts,
    'hierarchical' => $hierarchical,
    'title_li'     => $title,
    'hide_empty'   => $empty
);
$all_categories = get_categories( $args );
$lastCategory=end($all_categories);
$slug =$lastCategory->slug;
$title=$lastCategory->name;
$thumbnail_id= get_post_thumbnail_id($lastCategory->id );

// If the page doesn't already exist, then create it

if( null == get_page_by_title( $title ) ) {

// Set the post ID so that we know the post was created successfully

    $post_id = wp_insert_post(

        array(

            'post_author'   => $author_id,
            'post_name'   => $slug,
            'post_title'    => $title,
            'post_status'   => 'publish',
            'post_type'   => 'us_portfolio',
            'post_parent' =>11,
            'page_template' =>'custumcat.php',
            'post_slug'=> $slug

        )

    );


    update_post_meta($post_id, '_wp_page_template', 'custumcat.php' );
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_thumbnail_id', $thumbnail_id );

// Otherwise, we'll stop

} else {

    // Arbitrarily use -2 to indicate that the page with the title already exists

    $post_id = -2;

} // end if
} // end programmatically_create_post


add_action('create_product_cat', 'programmatically_create_post', 10,2);
```

I want set portfolio thumbnail from category thumbnail, and
I have used  `$thumbnail_id= get_post_thumbnail_id($lastCategory->id );`for get category thumbnail.

After that  I used `update_post_meta( $post_id, '_thumbnail_id', $thumbnail_id );` to set portfolio's thumbnail.

**But it doesn't set anything.**

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update 2.1**

I have been testing the code below and I got the correct **`$thumbnail_id`** with **no errors**:

```
$categories = get_categories( array(
    'taxonomy'     => 'product_cat',
    'orderby'      => 'id',
    'show_count'   => 0,
    'pad_counts'   => 0,
    'hierarchical' => 1,
    'title_li'     => '',
    'hide_empty'   => 0
) );

$last_cat = end($categories); // last category

$last_cat_term_id = $last_cat->term_id; // Value is

$thumbnail_id = get_woocommerce_term_meta( $last_cat_term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true );
echo 'Term ID is: ' . $last_cat_term_id . '<br>';
echo 'Thumbnail ID is: ' . $thumbnail_id;
```

It displays the last category (with this data related to my product categories settings):

```css
Term ID is: 48
Thumbnail ID is: 443
```

And here the corresponding screenshot of the DB table "wp_termmeta":

[image: // Displays 443 (the correct 'thumbnail_id'set in DB table "wp_termmeta")]

> So this is tested and works.
>
> This time, **`update_post_meta( $post_id, '_thumbnail_id', $thumbnail_id );`** will set correctly a value.

…

---

**Update 1:**

Product categories are a WordPress custom taxonomy that uses **`WP_terms`**…

This doesn't work because **`$lastCategory->id`** doesn't exist (and output a null value):

```
$thumbnail_id= get_post_thumbnail_id($lastCategory->id );
```

Instead you need to use **`$lastCategory->term_id`** that will work with **`WP_Term`** object and [**`get_woocommerce_term_meta()`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45283081/woocommerce-get-attribute-thumbnail-variation-swatches-and-photos-plugin/45283528#45283528) this way:

```
$thumbnail_id= get_woocommerce_term_meta( $lastCategory->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true );
```

The [**`WP_Term`**](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/class-wp-term.php#L252) object properties are:

```
term_id 
name
slug
term_group
term_taxonomy_id
taxonomy
description 
parent
count
```

Related to product category term: [WooCommerce get attribute thumbnail - Variation Swatches and Photos plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45283081/woocommerce-get-attribute-thumbnail-variation-swatches-and-photos-plugin/45283528#45283528)

Comment: In phpstorme drow a line on get_woocommerce_term_meta, but it work and i get thumbnail id ,but it doesnt set on portfolio page

Comment: but my question is why it doesn't set ?Ok i finish this question and ask again why it doesn't set. thanks Mr

Comment: @zeynabfarzaneh Some advice for your new question, you should also add the related code for template `custumcat.php` (or a link to it) and some more details on this template. Please see: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) … *(you don't need to answer to this comment)*

Answer (score 0):

First of all, a WooCommerce product category is a `taxonomy`, not a `post`, so you cannot use the function `get_post_thumbnail_id()` on it.
Instead, you can use something like this:

```
$thumbnail_id = get_woocommerce_term_meta( $term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true );
```

Second, since your `programmatically_create_post` function is a hook for `create_product_cat`, when invoked, it receives 2 parameters: $term_id and $term_taxonomy_id.
There is no need to look up the just created product category via all these lines (get_categories() shouldn't even work, because you work with product categories here, not regular post categories):

```
$all_categories = get_categories( $args );
$lastCategory=end($all_categories);
```

when you can simply declare your function like

```
function programmatically_create_post($term_id, $tt_id) {...}
```

then simply make use of the `$term_id` parameter:

```
$lastCategory = get_term($term_id, 'product_cat');
```

Make sure you also use `$term_id` instead of `$lastCategory->id`.

Comment: I edited my code like you sad . but it doesn't work and doesn't add new category

Answer (score 0):

`get_woocommerce_term_meta` is deprecated since version 3.6
`Use get_term_meta instead.

```
get_term_meta( int $term_id, string $key = '', bool $single = false )
```

Codex [reference documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term_meta/)