# Is there anywhere to get attribute images from WooCommerce Rest API? I've tried every endpoint I can find and so far no data

Tags: javascript, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

So I'm creating a react feature and need access to the data that exists inside the Wordpress site in order to do so. I need to allow customers to purchase products which have variations. The variations each have their own image which I need to display.

I have tried the following endpoints and have no image data at all (except the empty array for this image plugin which isn't want I want because I can't dynamically associate them with the individual attributes):

`/products/{productId}`
`/products/attributes/`
`/products/attributes/{attributeId}`
`/products/attributes/{attributeId}/terms`
`/products/{productId}/variations/{variationId}`

I'm unable to get any data related to the images I have set. Here is an screenshot of my product attribute, with selected image in `woocommerce > attributes`:

[image: Woocommerce Attribute with Image]

Now here are some responses I'm getting:

**/products/{productId}**

```
{
    "id": 1001,
    "name": "Large Duck",
    "slug": "large-duck",
    "permalink": "https://example.com/product/large-duck/",
    "date_created": "2023-05-22T23:53:05",
    "date_created_gmt": "2023-05-22T23:53:05",
    "date_modified": "2023-05-23T12:12:20",
    "date_modified_gmt": "2023-05-23T12:12:20",
    "type": "variable",
    "status": "publish",
    "featured": false,
    "catalog_visibility": "visible",
    "description": "",
    "short_description": "",
    "sku": "",
    "price": "50",
    "regular_price": "",
    "sale_price": "",
    "date_on_sale_from": null,
    "date_on_sale_from_gmt": null,
    "date_on_sale_to": null,
    "date_on_sale_to_gmt": null,
    "on_sale": false,
    "purchasable": true,
    "total_sales": 0,
    "virtual": false,
    "downloadable": false,
    "downloads": [],
    "download_limit": -1,
    "download_expiry": -1,
    "external_url": "",
    "button_text": "",
    "tax_status": "taxable",
    "tax_class": "",
    "manage_stock": false,
    "stock_quantity": null,
    "backorders": "no",
    "backorders_allowed": false,
    "backordered": false,
    "low_stock_amount": null,
    "sold_individually": false,
    "weight": "",
    "dimensions": {
        "length": "",
        "width": "",
        "height": ""
    },
    "shipping_required": true,
    "shipping_taxable": true,
    "shipping_class": "",
    "shipping_class_id": 0,
    "reviews_allowed": true,
    "average_rating": "0.00",
    "rating_count": 0,
    "upsell_ids": [],
    "cross_sell_ids": [],
    "parent_id": 0,
    "purchase_note": "",
    "categories": [
        {
            "id": 20,
            "name": "Riot OG",
            "slug": "riot-og"
        }
    ],
    "tags": [],
    "images": [],
    "attributes": [
        {
            "id": 4,
            "name": "Strength",
            "position": 0,
            "visible": true,
            "variation": true,
            "options": [
                "Low strength",
                "Medium strength",
                "Full strength"
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "name": "Flavour",
            "position": 1,
            "visible": true,
            "variation": true,
            "options": [
                "Bubblegum",
                "Lemon",
                "Mint",
                "Tobacco"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "default_attributes": [],
    "variations": [
        1011
    ],
    "grouped_products": [],
    "menu_order": 0,
    "price_html": "<span class=\"woocommerce-Price-amount amount\"><bdi><span class=\"woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol\">&pound;</span>50.00</bdi></span>",
    "related_ids": [
        997,
        999
    ],
    "meta_data": [
        {
            "id": 9079,
            "key": "site-sidebar-layout",
            "value": "default"
        },
        {
            "id": 9080,
            "key": "site-content-layout",
            "value": "default"
        },
        {
            "id": 9081,
            "key": "theme-transparent-header-meta",
            "value": "default"
        }
    ],
    "stock_status": "instock",
    "has_options": true,
    "_links": {
        "self": [
            {
                "href": ""
            }
        ],
        "collection": [
            {
                "href": ""
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

**/products/attributes/5/terms/42**

```
{
        "id": 42,
        "name": "Mint",
        "slug": "mint",
        "description": "Mint flavour",
        "menu_order": 0,
        "count": 1,
        "_links": {
            "self": [
                {
                    "href": "https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products/attributes/5/terms/42"
                }
            ],
            "collection": [
                {
                    "href": "https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products/attributes/5/terms"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

**/products/1001/variations/1011**

```
{
    "id": 1011,
    "date_created": "2023-05-23T10:45:04",
    "date_created_gmt": "2023-05-23T10:45:04",
    "date_modified": "2023-05-23T10:49:04",
    "date_modified_gmt": "2023-05-23T10:49:04",
    "description": "",
    "permalink": "https://example.com/product/large-duck/",
    "sku": "",
    "price": "50",
    "regular_price": "50",
    "sale_price": "",
    "date_on_sale_from": null,
    "date_on_sale_from_gmt": null,
    "date_on_sale_to": null,
    "date_on_sale_to_gmt": null,
    "on_sale": false,
    "status": "publish",
    "purchasable": true,
    "virtual": false,
    "downloadable": false,
    "downloads": [],
    "download_limit": -1,
    "download_expiry": -1,
    "tax_status": "taxable",
    "tax_class": "",
    "manage_stock": false,
    "stock_quantity": null,
    "stock_status": "instock",
    "backorders": "no",
    "backorders_allowed": false,
    "backordered": false,
    "low_stock_amount": null,
    "weight": "",
    "dimensions": {
        "length": "",
        "width": "",
        "height": ""
    },
    "shipping_class": "",
    "shipping_class_id": 0,
    "image": null,
    "attributes": [],
    "menu_order": 1,
    "meta_data": [],
    "woo_variation_gallery_images": [],
    "_links": {
        "self": [
            {
                "href": "https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products/1001/variations/1011"
            }
        ],
        "collection": [
            {
                "href": "https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products/1001/variations"
            }
        ],
        "up": [
            {
                "href": "https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products/1001"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Guess you would have to go via https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#retrieve-a-product-attribute, and if you don't know the attribute ID, probably via https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#list-all-product-attributes first.

Comment: @CBroe thanks for the response. I have also tried /products/attributes list and individual ID and still no image data. I can find everything I need except for any image URLs

Comment: Guess you will probably have to go a similar way to https://stackoverflow.com/a/45283528/1427878 then - get the term meta data field that holds the image first (not sure if that is directly possible; perhaps you need to extend the Rest API with your own custom endpoints for that), and then go via `/wp/v2/media/<id>`.